# Does TEXT in MySQL retain spaces/formatting for XML?

Tags: mysql, xml

If I embed XML into a TEXT column in MySQL, will it retain the spacing/indentation of the XML blob? Will I need to fix the markup when I retrieve it so it isn't just a long string?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html), the text you put in will stay untouched (except for possible truncation if you try to put more text in than the datatype can accept).  Indeed, there are few differences with `VARCHAR`: no `DEFAULT` value, and, if you put an index on a `TEXT` column, you *must* specify the prefix length, which is only optional for `VARCHAR`.